# what should be the size of gate?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, autocad

what should be the size of gate?
if street 8 ft
according to house map Car entrance gate 11 ft

can corolla grande car enter into the gate easily with some moves?

Comment: See this and other posts : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/18714/10902

Answer (score 2):

For a 90 degree entrance of a compact car you need minimum 20 feet clear radius per city of Los Angeles parking code. This means if your alley is 8 foot wide you need a space leading to the gate of 12 feet by 12bfeet clear. But the gate itself can be 8'6" wide provided it is located at the far side of that clear space.

Or you can try measuring the space you need by finding a vacant parking lot, tree orange traffic cones. Use one to Mark the inside turn corner and the other two to Mark star and end of turn for the front bumper. Allow at least 6 inches clearance for the mirrors and the sweeping inside mid column.

Pay extra attention to backing out, you be surprised how much the front suspension drags out before a turn starts. If you watch the semi trucks backing into a truck dock you see how much extra space is needed.
I have attached a screenshot of the city of LA chart, they basically require a 37 feet square clear. 
[image: City of Los Angeles digram]